# What is the default bind address used when opening an SSH tunnel without explicitly specifying it

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-tunneling

When opening an SSH tunnel, e.g. as follows on Ubuntu 21.10:

```bsh
$ ssh -f -N -L 1234:127.0.0.1:5678 user@server
```

what is(are) the *default* bind address(es) used under the hood (if any)?

Is this equivalent to:

```bsh
$ ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:1234:127.0.0.1:5678 user@server
```

or

```bsh
$ ssh -f -N -L 0.0.0.0:1234:127.0.0.1:5678 user@server
```

or something like

```bsh
$ ssh -f -N -L *:1234:127.0.0.1:5678 user@server
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to `man ssh`

> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may be used
> to bind the connection to a specific
> address.  The bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use only, while an empty address or
> ‘*’ indicates that the port should be
> available from all interfaces.

so it should be **all** interfaces.

you can check from another terminal using `ss -tlp` (as non root) and check for a line with ssh.

Comment: So it's perfectly equivalent with the star `*` expression then. Thanks.